# Want to add a new plugin using composer instead of updating all plugins

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I want to add a particular plugin in my laravel app using composer. I don't want to sync whole of the plugins with composer.json, I just want to add a new plugin.

If I remove rest of the plugins and add a json value i.e. `"mgallegos/laravel-jqgrid": "1.*"`, once the files are downloaded, all of the plugins get removed because they are not mentioned there in json file.

Can I only add 1 particular plugin without making any changes in rest of the plugins?

Here is what my json file looks like:

[image]

Comment: `composer require mgallegos/laravel-jqgrid`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install particular package, use [require](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require) command like this:

```
composer require vendor/package_name ~version
```

To update only single package, use [update](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update) command:

```
composer update vendor/package_name
```

To [update](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update) multiple packages at once:

```
composer update vendor/package_name vendor/package_name2
```

**Options with update command:**

- --**prefer-source:** Install packages from source when available.
- --**prefer-dist:** Install packages from dist when available.
- --**ignore-platform-reqs:** ignore php, hhvm, lib-* and ext-* requirements and force the installation even if the local machine
  does not fulfill these. See also the platform config option.
- --**dry-run:** Simulate the command without actually doing anything.
- --**dev:** Install packages listed in require-dev (this is the default behavior).
- --**no-dev:** Skip installing packages listed in require-dev. The autoloader generation skips the autoload-dev rules.
- --**no-autoloader:** Skips autoloader generation.
- --**no-scripts:** Skips execution of scripts defined in composer.json.
- --**no-progress:** Removes the progress display that can mess with some terminals or scripts which don't handle backspace
  characters.
- --**optimize-autoloader (-o):** Convert PSR-0/4 autoloading to classmap to get a faster autoloader. This is recommended especially
  for production, but can take a bit of time to run so it is currently
  not done by default.
- --**classmap-authoritative (-a):** Autoload classes from the classmap only. Implicitly enables --optimize-autoloader.
- --**lock:** Only updates the lock file hash to suppress warning about the lock file being out of date.
- --**with-dependencies:** Add also all dependencies of whitelisted packages to the whitelist.
- --**root-reqs:** Restricts the update to your first degree dependencies.
- --**prefer-stable:** Prefer stable versions of dependencies.
- --**prefer-lowest:** Prefer lowest versions of dependencies. Useful for testing minimal versions of requirements, generally used with --prefer-stable.

**Reference:** https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can add the new package to your `composer.json` and call `composer install`. This will **not** update your packages but only install the versions set in the `composer.lock` file and new packages.

Alternatively you can call `composer require thenew/package ~1.0`

Additional note: `composer install` will **never** update anything. If you have a `composer.lock` file and run `composer install`, composer will install the *exact same* version you had before. Only `composer update` will update to the latest version, matching your requested version-string.

Edit: It is recommended to don't touch the `vendor` directory at all. If you need to have a library changed: Fork it, change it, publish it under your namespace, so you can `composer require` it directly. This allows you to *always* recreate the same (working) vendor-directory with a `composer install` from scratch as long as your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` are intact.

Comment: I have made some modification in one of my plugins, so won't be even updating or sync-ing them.. the second options seems good to me

Comment: IIRC composer will not re-install existing packages, even if you modified them. But I recommend publishing the modified package under your namespace so you can just `require` your own version of it and don't need to redo all the changes when you need to re-install the packages (on a new host or something)